# Terraform provider "opensearch" "url" is required, but was not set

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I created provider opensearch for the elasticsearch configuration and have setup the opensearch domain correctly, can be seen here:

```
provider "opensearch" {
  url = "https://${aws_opensearch_domain.opensearch_domain.endpoint}"
  username = local.master_user_name
  password = random_password.opensearch-admin-password.result
  sign_aws_requests = false
  healthcheck = false
}
```

And this is my required providers setup:

```
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.48.0"
    }

    opensearch = {
      source  = "opensearch-project/opensearch"
      version = "2.1.0"
    }
  }
```

I'm getting the error when removing it now

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│ The argument "url" is required, but was not set.
```

Which is weird as there are no dependencies for it etc. I have the state file stored in aws s3.

Anyone know why I cannot remove the provider now when no one is depending on it?

Comment: Try removing the `.terraform` directory and running `terraform init`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you add the `required_providers` block as well to the question? Also, where is the OpenSearch domain coming from? Is all the code within the same root module?

Comment: I added the required_provider setup in the question now.

Comment: So you're trying to create the OpenSearch domain and configure the provider in one go?

Comment: Yes, but the opensearch domain is already created as of now. It worked fine before but then I deleted the opensearch domain and re-created it, and now I'm getting that error.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you can create the domain and configure the provider in one run.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need something like this.

```
required_providers {
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = "~> 4.48.0"
}

opensearch = {
  source  = "opensearch-project/opensearch"
  version = "2.1.0"
}}
provider "opensearch" {
  url = “https://your_opensearch_endpoint”
}
```

Here are more details on how you can authenticate to your domain.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/opensearch-project/opensearch/latest/docs